# aubio python bindings in os x lion

Tags: python, osx-lion, aubio

when i install aubio via macports (with the python variant), i cannot import the python aubio modules:

```
Python 2.5.6 (r256:88840, Sep 19 2011, 21:07:27) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2335.15.00)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import aubio.task
Fatal Python error: Interpreter not initialized (version mismatch?)
Abort trap: 6
```

when take a look in the crash details, i saw there are some OS X python modules referenced

```
Process:         Python [82676]
Path:            /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python
...
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.7.1 (11B2118)
...
Binary Images:
       0x10e728000 -        0x10e728ff7 +org.python.python (2.5a0 - 2.5alpha0) <73543922-3239-3C75-B88D-65AD5E0F06BA> /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python
       0x10e72d000 -        0x10e82dfe7 +org.python.python (2.5a0 - 2.5) <329BEC3B-F0C2-3FD0-97AA-109233898D29> /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/Python
       0x10e9be000 -        0x10e9c0ff7 +readline.so (??? - ???) <2650A260-23C4-3D2D-BB48-122E5BC91F15> /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/lib/python2.5/lib-dynload/readline.so
       0x10e9f6000 -        0x10e9f6fff  libmx.A.dylib (2026.0.0 - compatibility 1.0.0) <C23BF0A1-7E6D-35EF-85FE-651EE2C13D53> /usr/lib/libmx.A.dylib
       0x10e9f9000 -        0x10e9fcfef +libogg.0.dylib (9.0.0 - compatibility 9.0.0) <F6229EA6-E44B-3788-8DFA-C46C1D12F6C7> /opt/local/lib/libogg.0.dylib
       0x10eb00000 -        0x10eb28fff +libreadline.6.2.dylib (6.2.0 - compatibility 6.0.0) <57527480-D072-3099-9712-C50B102BBFE5> /opt/local/lib/libreadline.6.2.dylib
       0x10eb3e000 -        0x10eb7dfef +libncurses.5.dylib (5.0.0 - compatibility 5.0.0) <9FC5E997-7C15-3B1A-9953-8C1F2624ED31> /opt/local/lib/libncurses.5.dylib
       0x10ebcc000 -        0x10ebf8fff +_aubiowrapper.so (??? - ???) <56FDDC03-9A74-3C25-ACC1-0A65798455BF> /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/lib/python2.5/site-packages/aubio/_aubiowrapper.so
       0x10ec07000 -        0x10ec0cfff +libaubioext.2.dylib (4.1.0 - compatibility 4.0.0) <F6AC9BF3-26EE-3BEA-8250-072EFB6265C8> /opt/local/lib/libaubioext.2.dylib
       0x10ec10000 -        0x10ec68fe7 +libsndfile.1.dylib (2.25.0 - compatibility 2.0.0) <F425B83F-0A2C-3344-B9CD-368F0FCF5E04> /opt/local/lib/libsndfile.1.dylib
       0x10ec79000 -        0x10eca2ff7 +libFLAC.8.dylib (11.0.0 - compatibility 11.0.0) <F72873F0-7017-3226-A29F-6CFC911B6899> /opt/local/lib/libFLAC.8.dylib
       0x10ecae000 -        0x10ef24ff7 +libvorbisenc.2.dylib (3.8.0 - compatibility 3.0.0) <12B552C3-8DC8-328B-9DA5-B63A4636F18F> /opt/local/lib/libvorbisenc.2.dylib
       0x10ef61000 -        0x10ef89fe7 +libvorbis.0.dylib (5.5.0 - compatibility 5.0.0) <8FDD1FBB-D20E-3228-AB2E-67984C6F7C54> /opt/local/lib/libvorbis.0.dylib
       0x10ef93000 -        0x10f146fe7 +libfftw3.3.dylib (7.0.0 - compatibility 7.0.0) <AF4A5E38-2DA2-363D-8F7A-5CA9BD977C31> /opt/local/lib/libfftw3.3.dylib
       0x10f168000 -        0x10f2d1fef +libsamplerate.0.dylib (2.7.0 - compatibility 2.0.0) <45B924AB-9411-3C1C-9092-1C5FF3907234> /opt/local/lib/libsamplerate.0.dylib
       0x10f2d4000 -        0x10f2dffe7 +libaubio.2.dylib (4.1.0 - compatibility 4.0.0) <36E085DC-1122-34CE-9583-F0ACEE71AA5D> /opt/local/lib/libaubio.2.dylib
       0x10f2e4000 -        0x10f3ffff7  org.python.python (2.7.1 - 2.7.1) <51260C94-62B4-3EB7-BFE9-695FC6252FF5> /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Python
    0x7fff6e328000 -     0x7fff6e35cac7  dyld (195.5 - ???) <4A6E2B28-C7A2-3528-ADB7-4076B9836041> /usr/lib/dyld
    0x7fff8bcb7000 -     0x7fff8bcbbfff  libmathCommon.A.dylib (2026.0.0 - compatibility 1.0.0) <FF83AFF7-42B2-306E-90AF-D539C51A4542> /usr/lib/system/libmathCommon.A.dylib
    0x7fff8cae7000 -     0x7fff8cae8fff  libsystem_sandbox.dylib (??? - ???) <8D14139B-B671-35F4-9E5A-023B4C523C38> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_sandbox.dylib
    0x7fff8e524000 -     0x7fff8e52eff7  liblaunch.dylib (392.18.0 - compatibility 1.0.0) <EB5C4B29-D3B7-38AC-A646-3D445C767F03> /usr/lib/system/liblaunch.dylib
...
```

how can i avoid the linking to the OSX python2.7 bindings and use the macport python2.5 libs instead? (i have already done a "sudo port select python python25" and recompiled everything without success)

thx for help. max.

Answer (score 0):

That appears to be a bug in the MacPorts port of `audio`.  You should not have to do anything to have it link to the MacPorts Python 2.5.  I suggest [opening a ticket](http://guide.macports.org/#project.tickets) about it.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the latest git:

```
$ git clone git://git.aubio.org/git/aubio
$ cd aubio/
$ ./waf configure build
$ cd python
$ python setup.py build
```

Answer (score 0):

In aubio 0.4.1 it looks like aubio.task no longer exists, so I get

```
ImportError: No module named task
```

To get it installed on Mac OS X, I found that downloading the tarballs:
http://aubio.org/bin/0.4.1/aubio-0.4.1.darwin_binary.tar.bz2
and 
http://aubio.org/bin/0.4.1/python-aubio-0.4.1.macosx-10.8-intel.tar.gz
and manually copying everything into place did the trick.